# Why does fresh Next.js app have this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have tried this multiple times, my head is aching from anger and disappointment in myself, please help.  So I try to create an app with :
`npx create-next-app@latest --ts`

this is the error I get instantly after running **next dev**:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (/Users/workingkakha/Documents/arcton/web/marketplace/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1618:21)
    at Html (webpack-internal:///../../../../../../opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:260:106)
    at renderWithHooks (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5661:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5734:15)
    at renderElement (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5949:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:6107:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:6079:14)
    at finishClassComponent (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5691:3)
    at renderClassComponent (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5699:3)
    at renderElement (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5946:7)
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (/Users/workingkakha/Documents/arcton/web/marketplace/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1618:21)
    at Head (/Users/workingkakha/Documents/arcton/web/marketplace/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/head.js:202:34)
    at renderWithHooks (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)
    at renderElement (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderNode (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
    at renderChildrenArray (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7) {
  page: '/'
}
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (/Users/workingkakha/Documents/arcton/web/marketplace/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1618:21)
    at Html (webpack-internal:///../../../../../../opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:260:106)
    at renderWithHooks (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5661:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5734:15)
    at renderElement (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5949:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:6107:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:6079:14)
    at finishClassComponent (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5691:3)
    at renderClassComponent (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5699:3)
    at renderElement (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.browser.development.js:5946:7)
```

I have no more ideas on how to fix it, I am not even changing the project, it just wont run. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Okay, I just tried npm run dev and it worked, granted I am stupid, but someone please explain why is this happening!?

Comment: This is a known issue -> https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38617

Answer (score 0):

run "yarn run dev". I was making the mistake of running "next dev"
on the Next JS doc it says
//
After the installation is complete:

Run npm run dev or yarn dev or pnpm dev to start the development server on http://localhost:3000

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).